# how to set orientation to correct device orientation after dismissModalViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation, landscape-portrait

i have a detailview where content is displayed. with a button i am presenting another view modally:

```
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:helpViewController animated:NO];
```

So, when i dismiss this helpViewController, the detailview is always in portraitMode.
Cant get it to the correct device orientation.

I have tried it with this to rotate it to device orientation:

```
if ([UIViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(  
    attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation)]) {

    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}
```

It seems that after dismissing the helpViewController viewDidAppear is not called in detailView.
**So how can i get that to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try to set the detailview.m as

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
//    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

Comment: the return value of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is already set to YES, but still doesnt work.

Comment: and how about the parent view of the detailview?

Comment: So all rotate well before present the helpView?

Comment: exactly. just when returning from helpview, detailview is locked in portraidMode.

Comment: oh, it is not. but dont know why. What can here the problem?

Comment: I don't know. Is the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method called when the detailView appeared?

Comment: i have solved it, you pointed me to right direction. presented with self.viewcontroller wich makes helpview not rotable. presented with `[self presentMod...]` have solved it. thank you.

Comment: Congratulations! My pleasure:)